# Why do my label and input appear in my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm mocking up a site as an assignment and my text is appearing behind my nav bar. I need it to be under the nav bar how can I fix this?

so I've tried setting the margin-bottom to 50px and setting it as important.
I've tried setting the nav bar as static.

I've tried messing with a bunch of different settings as well but I can't seem to find something to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="gregslist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
   <header>
        <nav> 

            <ul>
                <li class="greg">Greg's List</li>
                <li><a href="Post.asp">Post</a></li>
                <li><a href="Account.asp">Account</a> </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
    </header>

  <body>
    <div class="search"> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Software Jobs"> </input>
      <label> Search Jobs </label> </div>


  </body>
</html>



head{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
height:100%vh;

}

nav{
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:#dddd;
  position:fixed;
  padding:10px;
}

ul {
  width:100%vp;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    text-align:center;

}

 .greg{
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:25px;
  }

li a {
    display:block;
    padding:8px;
    color:purple;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your nav is `position: fixed;`, it doesn't push the rest of your content down the page. Anything absolutely positioned, be it `absolute`,`sticky`, or `fixed`, is not a part of the DOM in the same way that a normal element is. To non-absolute positioned elements it may as well not exist. What you want to do is add a `margin-top` to your content like this:

```css
head{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
height:100%vh;

}

nav{
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:#dddd;
  position:fixed;
  padding:10px;
}

ul {
  width:100%vp;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    text-align:center;

}

 .greg{
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:25px;
  }

li a {
    display:block;
    padding:8px;
    color:purple;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;

    }

body{
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="gregslist.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
     <header>
        <nav> 

            <ul>
                <li class="greg">Greg's List</li>
                <li><a href="Post.asp">Post</a></li>
                <li><a href="Account.asp">Account</a> </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="search"> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Software Jobs"> </input>
      <label> Search Jobs </label> </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This HTML markup is also invalid. `<header>` should be inside the `<body>`

Comment: Didn't even notice, I copy and pasted the OP's code. I'll edit mine. This solution will still work tho.